# VB.Net reuse sql connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm a newbie to vb.net, I'd like to ask is there a way to reuse the sql connection command?

Here is the code for my main.vb:

```
 Dim ServerString As String = "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=;Database=pos"
 Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

 Private Sub Main_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SQLConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString

    Try
        If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            SQLConnection.Open()
        Else
            SQLConnection.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Since I'd like to use this in my other classes, i don't want to re-write this code in every form. Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusing a connection (or any other unmanaged resource) is normally not a good idea. You should dispose them as soon as possible.

But there's no problem in always creating a new connection anyway, since you're using the [ADO.NET connection-pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) by default. So you are not creating (and opening) a new physical connection.  Actually you're just telling the pool that a conenction is reusable somewhere else now when you close/dispose it. And when you open it, it cannot be used somewhere else, that's why it's important to always close it.

Therefore always use the [`Using`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx).

```
Public Shared Function GetColumn1(column2 As Int32) As String
    Dim sql = "SELECT Column1 From dbo.tableName WHERE Column2=@Column2 ORDER BY Column1 ASC"
    Using con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", column2)
            Try
                con.Open()
                Using rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If rd.Read() Then
                        Dim Column1 As String = rd.GetString(0)
                        Return Column1
                    Else
                        Return Nothing
                    End If
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' log the exception here or do not catch it '
                ' note that you don't need a Finally to close the connection '
                ' since a Using-Statement disposes the object even in case of exception(which also closes a connection implicitely)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Above is a sample method to demontrate that you should not reuse anything.

Comment: thanks! By the way, can you update you code? So I can start working with it.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: i've tried to provide something useful even if you've not showed what you're actually tring to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I normally do:  I create a class, e.g. ConnectDB, and a method within this class, e.g. GetConnection.  Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class ConnectDB

    Public Shared Function GetConnection() As SqlConnection
        Dim dbConnString As String = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"
        Return New SqlConnection(dbConnString)
    End Function
End Class


Then from the method that needs a connection to the database, I call this function.  Here is a sample code:

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class EmployeeDB

    Public Shared Function GetEmployees() As List(Of Employee)
        Dim con As SqlConnection = ConnectDB.GetConnection()
        Dim selectStmt As String = "SELECT * FROM Employees"
        Dim selectCmd As New SqlCommand(selectStmt, con)
        Dim employees As New List(Of Employee)

        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader()
            Do While reader.Read
                Dim employee as New Employee

                employee.LastName = reader("LastName").ToString
                employee.FirstName = reader("FirstName").ToString
                ...
                employees.Add(employee)
            Loop
            reader.Close()
         Catch ex As Exception
             Throw ex
         Finally
             con.Close()
         End Try
         Return employees
    End Function
End Class
```

You can also modify the `selectStmt` string to include filter conditions, parameters, and sort order just like Tim's example above and include `selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@<parameterName>", value)` for each of your parameters.